# ElectronJs and Angular application, cookies not set on file:// protocol

Tags: angular, cookies, electron, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

We have an Angular 10 application inside Electron(v10.1.3). When in development mode we load content that is served by Angular CLI on localhost. Everything works fine, CORS, same-site policy, cookies are set when set-cookie header is present.

```
win.loadURL('http://localhost:4200')
```

But when in production mode, source files are loaded on file:// protocol:

```
win.loadURL(
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true,
        })
    )
```

The problem is, that when in production mode, cookies are not set. Requests are sent to restApi that returns set-cookie header, but they are ignored by Electron when pages are loaded from file:// protocol

When in development mode:

[image]

When in production mode:

[image]

I've tried registering a custom file protocol but with no success.
I've tried to add request headers with the correct Host, Origin, and Referrer values.

What am I missing here? How do I configure Electron when files are loaded from file:// so that it acts the same as a website is in an ordinary browser?

Comment: any update on this question?